# dark image in Skype but without a problem in other apps

Tags: ubuntu, video, elementary-os, camera, skype

I've just moved to Linux Family. I installed Elementary OS 64bit (based on Ubuntu).

I try to configure my Skype, but the video image is really dark. It is working, but it is low in contrast.

I've downloaded Cheese and the image there is great.

I've download Guvcview and the image there is great as well. But, when I run the guvcview, I have a lot of errors in terminal.

The weird is that when I have guvcview opened with the great image and open the preview of Skype camera, then then image of the first one gets darker too.

```
guvcview 1.5.3

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:756:1: Expected semicolon

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:776:0: Expected a valid selector

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:150:14: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:150:14: Junk at end of value

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: granite-widgets.css:144:14: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: granite-widgets.css:144:16: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: granite-widgets.css:144:22: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: toolbar.css:110:13: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(guvcview:19393): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: toolbar.css:110:13: Junk at end of value
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
video device: /dev/video0 
Init. TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD (location: usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3)
{ pixelformat = 'YUYV', description = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'MJPG', description = 'MJPEG' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'RGB3', description = 'RGB3' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'BGR3', description = 'BGR3' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'YU12', description = 'YU12' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'YV12', description = 'YV12' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
vid:04ca 
pid:7012 
driver:uvcvideo
checking format: 1196444237
VIDIOC_G_COMP:: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fps is set to 1/25
drawing controls

no codec detected for H264
no codec detected for MP3 - (lavc)
Checking video mode 640x480@32bpp : OK
```

Comment: My guess is skype tries to initialize the device to zero, where guvc hits the proper ioctls to set the contrast/brightness etc to sane 50% defaults.  This can be set at the device level with v4l2, but I'm not sure if you can do it from the command-line while skype is holding on to the device.

Answer (score 3):

The [`v4l2ucp`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/v4l2ucp/) package contains a video-settings GUI. You can use it to alter the `skype` video settings during a video call.